Install Google Authentication on react js app with capacitor. Sign in causing failure
I am getting the following error when trying to sign in on my ios device. It works percecrtly fine on android.
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Your app is missing support for the following URL schemes: com.googleusercontent.apps.#'
*** First throw call stack:

I have added the url scheme to info.plist

<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>com.googleusercontent.apps.#</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>#.apps.googleusercontent.com</string>
            </array>
        </dict>```


2. My app delegate


import UIKit
import Capacitor
import WebKit
import GoogleSignIn  // Ensure this is properly imported
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
var window: UIWindow?
// Set up Google Sign-In configuration with client ID
let signInConfig = GIDConfiguration(clientID: "#.apps.googleusercontent.com")

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    if let window = window {
        if let webView = window.rootViewController?.view.subviews.first(where: { $0 is WKWebView }) as? WKWebView {
            webView.configuration.preferences.setValue(true, forKey: "developerExtrasEnabled")
            webView.configuration.preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true  // Ensure JS is enabled
        }
    }
    return true
}

func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Handle the app transitioning to the background state.
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Handle entering background.
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Handle entering foreground.
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Handle app becoming active.
}

func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Handle app termination.
}

func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey: Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.handle(url)  // Handle the URL after Google Sign-In
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
    return ApplicationDelegateProxy.shared.application(application, continue: userActivity, restorationHandler: restorationHandler)
}

}```

I have also added the GoogleServices-info into app/app also.

I am lost been trying to figure a solution for like 4 hours. If anyone has had this issue before or any help on this would be greatly appreciate.
Thanks!
update google auth is working. The issue seems to be with how ios is initialising firebase. Analytics is working but auth is not. It does not seem to fire at all, which is causing this issue to authenticate the user.
